# Icons change size and display-attribute on different computers

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

On my website I have a few icons that are in a  and it all looks fine on my computer (Macbook Pro 13") and in both Safari and Chrome.
But when I visit my site from a 11" Macbook Air in Chrome or Safari, the icons on my contact page are tiny and the contacts inside different jobs I´ve done are messing about, changing display:inline and size changes when I hover on the ones next to the links to company websites..

They are all %-based and should not act like this.

This is my contact page icons:

HTML:

```
<div id="contact_me">

<ul>
 <li><a href="mailto:hello@niklaskoskela.com">
 <img src="img/mail.png" alt="email me"></a></li>
 <li><a href="mailto:hello@niklaskoskela.com">
 <p>HELLO@NIKLASKOSKELA.COM</p></a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/niklas-sidhu-koskela/68/20b/593" target="_blank">
 <img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="find me on Linked in"></a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/niklas-sidhu-koskela/68/20b/593" target="_blank">
 <p>NIKLAS SIDHU KOSKELA</p></a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li><a href="https://twitter.com/don_koskela" target="_blank">
 <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="follow me on Twitter"></a></li>
 <li><a href="https://twitter.com/don_koskela" target="_blank">
 <p>@DON_KOSKELA</p></a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contact_me ul {
    height: 80%;
    width: auto;    
}
contact_me ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20%;
    width: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

contact_me ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

contact_me ul li p {
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    color: #7a7a7a;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: 100;
}

contact_me ul li p:hover {
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    color: #cc7e47;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: 100;
}

contact_me ul li img{
    height: 9%;
    display: inline;
}
```

And here is the icons in my different projects:

HTML:

```
<div class="info">
 <ul class="details">
  <li><img src="img/skills.png" alt="skills">
  <h3>MOTION GRAPHICS, VIDEOGRAPHER</h3></li>
  <li><img src="img/period.png" alt="period">
  <h3>MAR 2012 - APR 2012</h3></li>
  <li><img src="img/website.png" alt="project website">
  <a href="http://www.addmorecolors.com" target="_blank">
  <h3>WWW.ADDMORECOLORS.COM</h3></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.info{

    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    width: 45%;

}

.info ul{

    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 5%;

}

.info ul li{

    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.info ul li img{

    width: 13%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.info ul li a{

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6dc4c8;

}

.info ul li a:hover{

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #cc7e47;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cc7e47;

}

.info ul li h3{

    display: inline;
    padding-top: 7%;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Hope someone can help me with this, I am completely lost...

Regards

Comment: You could try setting a 'min-width:' for your icons?

Comment: That did help. However, the point of them being based on % is so that they follow the viewers resolution. Setting them to min-width: 50px; for example, might make them unproportionally big at some resolutions, right?

Comment: Yes possibly, I haven't tested that unfortunately. As far as I know the images should already scale up and down without any problems on any browser, in the way you made them.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this by using @media query's and a viewport in your css , and add this meta tag to your html:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0”>
```

and with the @media query's and viewport you declare what size you have per screen width using this media query + viewport in css:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 820px) and (max-width: 920px) {
  @viewport { width: 820px; }
```

// your css for screens between 820 and 920 pixels in width goes here

```
  }
```

i mostly use the value's : from 20 - 600 , 600-700 , 700-820 , 820 - 920 , 920 - 1200,   @media screen and (min-width: 1200px){  @viewport { width: 1200px; }(this last one will set the size for any screen bigger than 1200 px in width so  your code for the biggest version goeds here}

So this means you will have 6 times your css code which is adapted will be adapted to the size.

This is called adaptive or responsive design and is pretty easy to do

For more info you might check this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thank you user3432892! I guess that´s the only solution... was hoping for a quicker and simpler one.
But I appreciate the help and will use this way